# if statement inside image source uri - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

There is an api that sometimes send empty field for image urls and react native tell me source.uri should not be empty but I am more worried because it breaks my grid layout. I would like to use a placeholder of the same size to fix that. 
This is what I tried so far

```
<View>
    <Image source={{ !this.item.thumbnail.length ? uri: 
    item.thumbnail : {require('/assets/images/placeholder.jpg')} }} />
</View>
```

Could any one please help.

Comment: `placeholder.jog` or `placeholder.jpg` ?

Comment: What is `uri: item.thumbnail` supposed to be?

Comment: @adam using flatlist and render item

Comment: @dacre-denny typo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are quite close in your attempt, but the syntax is not right. You just need to make sure that in one branch of the ternary, you return an object with a `uri` field, and in the other, you return the `require` call directly (don't wrap it as you've done in your example).

EG:

```
<Image
    // Note there is only a single enclosing brace here:
    source={this.item.thumbnail.length
        ? {uri: item.thumbnail}                      // Use object with 'uri'
        : require('/assets/images/placeholder.jpg')} // Or use require call directly
/>
```

*Note:* I reversed your condition which seemed backwards to me. You want to use the thumbnail when it has a non-zero length, and a placeholder otherwise, so I removed the negation.

Comment: There's definitely a syntax error there, also I didn't tried this.item.thumbnail.length so not sure it's working

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. I've been struggling with every combo of curly and round braces and this did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using a third party library solve my problem :

```
import ImageLoad from 'react-native-image-placeholder';

<View>
  <ImageLoad style={styles.pix} source={{uri: item.thumbnail}}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not strictly fall within the scope of your question, but it might help.
Why not define the source as a variable outside of the `return()`

Something like:

```
let newSauce = !this.item.thumbnail.length ? uri: 
    item.thumbnail : {require('/assets/images/placeholder.jpg')}
return(
    <View>
         <Image source={{ newSauce }} />
    </View>
)
```

Comment: Using this inside FlatList, not sure item.thumbnail will pass trough, thank you anyway salvador